# Extracting specific values from a dictionary in iOS Shortcuts to display in a Choose from List menu?

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts

I have a REST endpoint that returns a body that looks like this:

```
"posts": [
  {
    "message": "This is another message",
    "created": "2019-12-27 21:33:54+10",
    "items": [...],
    "tags": [...],
    "toot_id": "12345"
  },
  {
    "message": "This is a message",
    "created": "2019-12-26 20:42:15+10",
    "items": [...],
    "tags": [...],
    "toot_id": "12344"
  }
]
```

I want to extract just the `message` and `toot_id` fields and use a "Choose from List" action to display the message text, and upon selection pass the corresponding toot_id of the chosen message to the next action. Unfortunately I'm greatly struggling with how to do this... I know Javascript and TypeScript and can handle this sort of thing in those languages with no problems, but iOS's Shortcuts app is thwarting me. I've got as far as a "Repeat with each item" with the `posts` key as a result of hitting my REST endpoint, but I'm stuck as to how to continue from there, and I'm not clear on whether I should be setting the various actions inside the loop to "as Text" or "as Dictionary" either.

Thanks!

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Comment: As in the actual shortcut file, or just the general approach?

Comment: the code that you are using for json decoding.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't even know _how_ I should be doing it. :D I'd tried a whole bunch of stuff a few days ago, none of which worked and I had deleted it, and it's currently sitting at a blank "Repeat with each item in <Dictionary Value>" (where Dictionary Value is the `posts` list in my original post) which is where I'm stuck right now, hence my StackOverflow post, heh. I don't understand enough about how Shortcuts/iOS handles this to be able to even know if I'm on vaguely the right track or not.

Comment: I was trying to follow [Apple's example about handling lists](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/shortcuts/apd9ba41d21b/3.2/ios/13.2) but that's just returning text from each repeat, and I can't manage to put together from that something that works for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a screenshot of how I got it to work in a similar situation.

[image: iOS shortcuts update dictionary in variable]

The key for me was the combination of "Get dictionary from Input" (use the variable), "Set Dictionary Value", and then "Set Variable". Trying to do "Set Dictionary Value" on the variable directly (in one step) never worked.

Comment: Ooo hmmm! How did you set up the "Set Name to ID in Dictionary" inside the repeat? I have the choice of Dictionary or Dictionary Value but I'm not clear on how that links up to the values that were retrieved from the contents of the URL...

Comment: Doesn't look like I can put a screenshot in a comment, but the "Name" and "ID" are the results of the first two steps in the repeat (it probably says something like "Dictionary Value" by default, but I renamed them -- you can also use the magic variable picker thing to tell which is which). Then the "Dictionary" is just the result of the "Get dictionary from Projects" above. Does that help?

Comment: Worked an absolute treat! That was entirely unintuitive, I wouldn't have figured it out without your help, cheers. :)